# Discriminate files from different drives in tarfile

Tags: python, gzip, tar, tarfile

I am trying to archive and compress multiple directories spread along multiple drives using the `tarfile` library.
The problem is that `tarfile` merges the paths even if two files are stored in different drives.
For example:

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open(r"D:\Temp\archive.tar.gz", "w:gz") as tf:
    tf.add(r"C:\files\foo")
    tf.add(r"D:\files\bar")
```

Will create an archive containing the following files:

```
archive.tar.gz
└─ files
   ├─ foo
   └─ bar
```

Is there a way of creating this?

```
archive.tar.gz
├─ C
|  └─ files
|     └─ foo
└─ D
   └─ files
      └─ bar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks **Loïc** for your answer, it helped me find the actual answer I was looking for. (And also made me waste about a hour because I got really confused with the linux and windows style paths you mixed up in your answer)...

```
import os
import tarfile

def create_archive(paths, arc_paths, archive_path):
    with tarfile.open(archive_path, "w:gz") as tf:
        for path, arc_path in zip(paths, arc_paths):
            tf.add(path, arcname=arc_path)

def main():
    archive = r"D:\Temp\archive.tar.gz"
    paths = [r"C:\files\foo", r"D:\files\bar"]
    # Making sure all the paths are absolute.
    paths = [os.path.abspath(path) for path in paths]
    # Creating arc-style paths
    arc_paths = [path.replace(':', '') for path in paths]
    # Create the archive including drive letters (if in windows)
    create_archive(paths, arc_paths, archive)
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `tarfile.addfile()` instead of `tarfile.add()` :

With TarInfo you can specify the filename which will be used in the archive.

Exemple :

```
with open(r"C:\files\foo", "rb") as ff:
    ti = tf.gettarinfo(arcname="C/files/foo", fileobj=ff)
    tf.addfile(ti, ff)
```

Or maybe, a faster solution :

```
tf.add('/path/to/dir/to/add/', arcname='C/files')
tf.add('/path/to/otherdir/to/add/', arcname='D/files')
```

Comment: I've changed your example code, since what you wrote uses `file` rather than `open` (which is deprecated, and gone in Python 3), and creating a TarInfo directly with the name doesn't populate all the other file stats, most importantly the size (with no size it won't put any data in the archive)

Comment: Alright thanks @Random832
How about that by the way : 
`tar.add('/path/to/dir/to/add/', arcname='C/files')` ?

Comment: Heh, I hadn't noticed that was there, I was focused on addfile since you'd mentioned it in your answer.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that the 1st path is the path to the file I want to compress (because it's being read using open) and the 2nd is the path within the archive.
Another thing I was wondering is - did you mean that the /path/to/dir/to/add/ will be a unix-style path? Or should I specify the windows-style path of the file I want to add?

Comment: @real_2 you're right, my answer got edited and this paragraph wasn't right then. And of course you can use any style path you'd like.